# Bootstrap momentarily displays hidden modal dialog on slow page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap 2.3.2 via the `bootstrap-sass-2.3.2.2` gem in a Rails app.

With the following HTML:

```
  <div class="modal hide fade fullscreen" id="myModal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h3></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <img src="">
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <a class="figureFullsizeLink btn" href="">Full-size</a>
      <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And links like these:

```
  <a href="#myModal" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-html="true">
  <img alt="Fig 1" class="figure" src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/..." title="..." />
  </a>
```

And the following javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    ...
    // hide the modal window onload
    $("#myModal").css("display", "none");
    ...
});
```

I get a momentary flash of the open modal dialog while the page is loading. (see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X-HwRpKAUh8 for an exampe).

Comment: not sure what exactly does your modal contain, though i assume that it should be hidden by default, ergo you should not hide with javascript

Comment: @mymlyn that's what I thought Bootstrap's `hide` class was supposed to do. But without the javascript or CSS the modal dialog starts opened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your jQuery code runs after the [DOM hierarchy has been fully constructed](https://api.jquery.com/ready/). Therefore the modal will be displayed when the DOM loads, and then the javascript will execute and hide the modal.

The easiest way to have the modal hidden by default is to set the CSS to:

```
#myModal{display:none};
```

Or, you can always place your jquery code within the

```
<head>
```

element of your page and it will execute before the DOM is constructed.

Comment: Thanks, that did it! I was confused by Bootstrap's `hide` class thinking that it did this for me. But after applying `display:none` to `#myModal` I no longer see the flash of the modal dialog.